# $(n!)!>n^{n!} \forall n \in \Bbb N^{\ge 4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, but I came across it in the reasoning of solving a problem for my Real Analysis homework. It was not directly part of the problem so it may be a unique question, but I'm sure somebody has thought about it at some point. The problem is in proving that:

$$(n!)!>n^{n!}\quad \forall n\in \Bbb N^{\geq4}$$

I plotted it on Wolfram Alpha, so I know it to be true. Additionally I had some faint trail of reasoning for why it should be so, but I could not figure out a proof.

Comment: I like how it just misses for $n=3$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n\ge5$. In the $n!$ terms that multiply together to yield $(n!)!$, the last $n!-n^2$ of them are bigger than $n^2$. Therefore
$$
(n!)! > (n^2)^{n!-n^2} = n^{2(n!)-2n^2} > n^{n!}.
$$
(The last inequality uses $n! > 2n^2$ for $n\ge5$; indeed, even $n! > n(n-1)(n-2) > 2n^2$ for $n\ge5$.) Of course the desired inequality can be verified directly for $n=4$.

As you can see, there's tons of slack in this inequality and argument; mjqxxxx's answer gives an idea of how much.

Comment: In fact we can do without $4$ as special case as we quickly get $(n!)!\ge (n^2)^{n!-n^2+1}\cdot n^{n^2-n+1}\cdot 3!>n^{2(n!)-n^2-n+3}$ for $n\ge 4$, hence need "only" $n!\ge n^2+n-3$

Answer (score 3):

Using Stirling's approximation, $N! \approx N \log N$, you can deduce that the log of the left-hand side satisfies
$$
\log \left((n!)!\right) \approx n! \log n!
$$
while the log of the right-hand side is
$$
\log \left(n^{n!}\right)=n!\log n;
$$
since $n! > n$ for $n>2$, the left-hand side clearly dominates for all but very small values of $n$.

Comment: That's a good way to think about it, thanks. But I'm looking for a more hands on proof.

Answer (score 2):

$$(n!)!\gt\left(\frac{n!}{e}\right)^{n!}\gt\left(\frac{n!}{3}\right)^{n!}\gt\left(n\right)^{n!}$$

Comment: Where do you get the first inequality

Comment: From this:$$k!\gt\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k.$$You can prove the last equation by induction.

Comment: How do you prove that first one you just commented, sorry its late and its bugging me lol